# Melhor algoritmo possível

Tags: complexidade-de-algoritmo

Venho novamente com uma dúvida voltada para a área de Complexidade de Algoritmos, mas desta vez como escolher o algoritmo mais eficiente, para isto vamos considerar as duas expressões abaixo:

Algoritmo 1: *f1(n) = 2n² +5n* operações
Algoritmo 2: *f2(n) = 500n + 4000* operações

Visto que o algoritmo 1 possui *O(n²)* e o algoritmo 2 *O(n)*, o algoritmo 1 é dado como o pior caso possível para esta solução, tendo o segundo como a solução mais eficaz e plausível.

A minha dúvida é saber se a escolha de um algoritmo mais eficiente é feita desta forma, pois estou progredindo na matéria, porém dúvidas são recorrentes.

Espero que possam me ajudar, e que eu tenha sido objetivo o suficiente, agradeço desde já.

Obrigado.

Comment: Quais os parâmetros usados para a comparação?

Comment: @MagicHat - Apenas análise assintótica

Comment: @MagicHat - Primeiro, eu achei este exemplo na internet enquanto procurava conteúdos para estudo, segundo, esta é a minha dúvida, não sei ao certo definir um melhor ou pior :/

Comment: Julguei também que o primeiro eu utilizo n² passos, e como uma funçao quadrática é maior que uma singular n... pensando bem, o crescimento de n² seria mais rápido, mas não sei o melhor

Comment: Por exemplo: Ao meu ver em se tratando de algo que será processado, em cada uma das das instruções são realizadas operações internas, então a 1º opção indica que há 4 operações e na 2º  apenas 3...Entretanto em outro cenário pode ser o contrário...

Comment: @MagicHat, "então a 1º opção indica que há 4 operações e na 2º apenas 3", como você chegou a conclusão que na primeira haveria 4 operações e no segundo 3?

Comment: 1º - Potência 2º 2xmultiplicação 3º adição... Ex: seu eu fizer 1+1+1+1+1+1+1 = 7 é pior que 7=7...

Comment: @MagicHat: Neste caso você faz os cálculos de quantas operações são feitas com base na quantidade de operações apresentadas na expressão? como o algoritmo 12n² +5n, possui 2 multiplicações, uma soma e uma potência, sendo assim 4 operações, esta era uma dúvida minha, foi sanada até o momento.

Comment: @MagicHat - então a última dúvida, o melhor algoritmo ali seria o segundo? e o pior caso o primeiro?

Comment: @MagicHat - Eu classificaria assim mesmo, primeiro como pior, eu não sei muito sobre isso

Comment: @MagicHat - Certo então, para estes comentários não se estenderem mais e sermos alertados (não sei como funciona), estarei encerrando aqui, com o que foi apresentado acho que posso tirar um bom proveito, você me ajudou bastante, muito obrigado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55583/discussion-between-felix-and-magichat).

Answer (score 8):

## Calculando o comportamento dos algoritmos

A análise da complexidade de um algoritmo demonstra qual seria o seu desempenho com entradas de tamanho tendendo ao infinito. No entanto, para um número razoável de elementos, isso pode não ser o caso.

Para o seu caso, existe algum número ***n*** para o qual, além dele, o algoritmo linear será sempre mais rápido. Entretanto, determinar qual é esse ***n*** é um tanto difícil, pois ele pode variar de máquina para máquina e uma operação no algoritmo ***f1*** pode demorar um tempo diferente do que uma operação no algoritmo ***f2***.

Assim sendo, até um determinado ponto, o algoritmo ***f2*** deve ser mais rápido, sendo então alcançado e ultrapassado por ***f1*** deste ponto em diante.

Supondo que os dois algoritmos tenham operações com as mesmas velocidades e rodem na mesma máquina sob as mesmas condições (o que provavelmente não é uma suposição válida no mundo real, mas vamos presumir isso para facilitar o cálculo), podemos encontrar o valor de ***n*** onde um algoritmo ultrapassa o outro assim:

> f1(n) = f2(n)
>   2n² + 5n = 500n + 4000
>   2n² - 495n - 4000 = 0
>   n = (495 ± sqrt(495² - 4 * 2 * - 4000)) / (2 * 2) [aplicação da fórmula de Bhaskara]
>   n = (495 ± sqrt(245025 + 32000)) / 4
>   n = (495 ± sqrt(245025 + 32000)) / 4
>   n = (495 ± sqrt(277025)) / 4
>   n = (495 ± 526.33) / 4
>   n = (495 + 526.33) / 4 **OU** n = (495 - 526.33) / 4
>   n = 1021.33 / 4 **OU** n = -31.33 / 4
>   n = 255.33 **OU** n = -7.83

Como **n < 0** não faz sentido (o tamanho da entrada não tem como ser menor que zero), então:

> **n = 255.33**

Ou seja, para um **n ≤ 255**, o algoritmo ***f1*** é mais rápido. Para **n ≥ 256**, o algoritmo ***f2*** será mais rápido. Prova disso é que:

> f1(255) **<** f2(255) → 131325 **<** 131500
>   f1(256) **>** f2(256) → 132352 **>** 132000

## Por que usa-se apenas o termo de maior grau e despreza-se as constantes?

Novamente, friso que a análise de complexidade é dada com um ***n*** tendendo ao infinito. Neste caso, numa expressão do tipo **2n² + 5n**, o fator **5n** rapidamente se tornará desprezível perto do **2n²**, e portanto pode ser deixado de lado. Semelhantemente, numa expressão **500n + 4000**, o fator **500n** crescerá tanto de modo que o **4000** se tornará desprezível. Por isso é que apenas o termo de maior grau é considerado na análise de complexidade.

Quanto às constantes multiplicativas, ao comparar-se expressões com diferentes graus quando ***n*** tende ao infinito, a constante também acaba por ser irrelevante. Por exemplo, sejam ***p*** e ***g*** duas constantes, onde ***p*** é muito pequena e ***g*** é muito grande. Ao comparar-se **pn²** com **gn** tendo ***n*** tendendo ao infinito, haverá algum ponto onde o fator **pn²** crescerá de tal modo que ultrapassará o valor de **gn** (tal como fiz no cálculo acima), e portanto a expressão de maior grau sempre vai ultrapassar a de menor grau, independente das constantes utilizadas. Desta forma, quando ***n*** tende ao infinito, faz sentido apenas de falar-se do termo de maior grau, desprezando-se os coeficientes e os termos de menor grau.

Uma outra consequência da eliminação das constantes é que se você tem dois algoritmos **A** e **B** com complexidades de tempo de graus diferentes, não importa qual seja a máquina mais rápida, mesmo que uma delas execute instruções 10 vezes mais rapidamente que a outra (ou 100 vezes, ou um milhão de vezes), sempre haverá algum ponto **n** onde o algoritmo com a complexidade de maior grau será mais lento que o de menor grau (é verdade que é possível que este ponto seja para um tamanho de entrada monstruoso e para um tempo absurdo e fora do aceitável no mundo real, mas mesmo assim esse ponto existe).

Por outro lado, se os dois algoritmos **C** e **D** têm complexidades com o mesmo grau, mas o **C** é mais 2 vezes mais lento, basta eu conseguir uma máquina que seja mais do que 2 vezes mais rápida e então o algoritmo **C** ultrapassará o **D**. Os termos de menor grau não irão interferir nisso para um **n** suficientemente grande porque ao conseguir uma máquina mais rápida, eu estarei multiplicando/dividindo os tempos dos termos de maior grau também, de forma que para um valor suficiente de **n** a diferença de desempenho obtida com os termos de maior grau irá superar qualquer deficiência referente aos termos de menor grau.

## Exemplos concretos

Um exemplo concreto onde algo assim acontece é na multiplicação de números: o algoritmo aprendido na escola é **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**, enquanto que o [algoritmo de Karatsuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) é bem mais complexo (e portanto tem constantes multiplicativas maiores), mas é **O(n<sup>(log<sub>2</sub> 3)</sup>)**. Para números grandes, o algoritmo de Karatsuba é mais rápido. Para números pequenos, usa-se o algoritmo aprendido na escola.

Aliás, há também o [algoritmo de Schönhage–Strassen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) que bate o algoritmo de Karatsuba em números bem grandes, com dezenas de milhares de casas decimais, tendo ele uma complexidade **O(n log(n) log(log(n)))**.

Assim sendo, para números pequenos, o algoritmo mais rápido é o da escola. Para os números de tamanho médio, o Karatsuba mostra-se mais rápido. Para os números bem grandes, usa-se o Schönhage–Strassen.

Finalmente, o [algoritmo de Fürer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm) em teoria bate o Schönhage–Strassen tendo complexidade **O(n log(n) 2<sup>3 log*(n)</sup>)**, mas suas constantes multiplicativas são tão altas que ele teoricamente só supera o Schönhage–Strassen em números com dezenas de quintilhões de dígitos (e por esse motivo ele é mais uma curiosidade teórica do que algo que você usaria na prática).

Ah, e eu nem entrei no mérito do [algoritmo de Toom-Cook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication) que é uma generalização do algoritmo da escola e do Karatsuba.

Um outro caso é o algoritmo [Timsort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) que é um algoritmo que utiliza internamente, de forma seletiva e dinâmica, o [*merge sort*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) ou o [*insertion sort*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) em diferentes partes dos dados dependendo de como eles estão organizados, tentando aproveitar o melhor de cada algoritmo onde for conveniente e tentando se aproveitar de ordenações parciais já existentes.

Ou seja, se você quiser perguntar "*qual o algoritmo mais eficiente?*", deve-se perguntar primeiro "*quais são os tamanhos da entrada que me interessam?*" - esse detalhe pode mudar tudo.

## O uso de O, Ω e Θ

Além disso, a análise com o **O** se refere ao pior caso, não ao caso médio ou ao melhor caso. Por exemplo, o [*quicksort*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) para entradas aleatórias tem um caso médio bem melhor que *merge sort*. Apesar de ambos terem casos médios **O(n log n)**, o *quicksort* tem constantes multiplicativas menores. Entretanto, o pior caso do *quicksort* é **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**, enquanto que o do *merge sort* sempre é **O(n log n)**.

A notação **O** significa um limite superior. Ou seja, um algoritmo com complexidade **O(n²)** nunca vai levar um tempo pior do que quadrático para executar. Entretanto, esse limite pode ser frouxo, tal como é no *quicksort*, onde embora ele execute no máximo em tempo quadrático, ele pode em vários casos executar em um tempo bem menor do que isso.

Também há o limite inferior, que é dado por **Ω**. O algoritmo *quicksort* é **Ω(n log n)** porque ele nunca roda em tempo menor do que **n log n**. Ou seja, enquanto que o **O** diz qual é o pior caso, o **Ω** diz qual é o melhor. O uso de **Ω** não é muito comum, mas serve para se definir um ponto a partir do qual seria impossível uma melhoria que não se restrinja apenas às constantes multiplicativas ou aos termos de menor grau. Por exemplo, é sabido que **Ω(n log n)** é o limite inferior para algoritmos de ordenação de elementos baseados em comparação, e portanto sabe-se que não existe e que é algo impossível ter-se um algoritmo de ordenação de elementos com tempo melhor do que **n log n**.

E quando o melhor e o pior caso coincidem, surge o **Θ**. Um algoritmo pode ser dito **Θ(*k*)** se ele sempre executar em tempo ***k***, tanto no melhor quanto no pior caso. Por exemplo, o *merge sort* é **Θ(n log n)**, pois em todos os casos ele tem um tempo proporcional a **n log n**.